# How to share models between several applications in Play! framework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm creating a web-portal with Play framework (several websites with on a single database).
How can I share one class containing model between several applications?
I do not want to synchronize manually the code between my applications 'cause this way is full of potential errors.
Thanks!
PS. I use PF 1.2.7 with pure Java.

Answer (score 1):

Why not putting your model in a dedicate project packaged in a jar.

And then reference this in your different Play projets ?